# Is it up to each site to decide which kind of questions go on main vs meta? Or is meta only for questions about the site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, per-site-meta, policy

My understanding about meta sites on Stack Exchange is that they are for asking questions about the sites themselves. "Meta questions".

But I've noticed that some site allow three kinds of questions:

1. Fully on-topic questions which go on their main site.
2. Questions on the literal topic of the site but outside the scope decided for the site's policy. These go on their meta site.
3. Questions about site site also go on the meta site.

Is this kind of thing against Stack Exchange policy, or is it up to each site to decide how to use their meta site?

Comment: Can you provide an example post of the second type?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: I'm reluctant to "name names" if it is against policy. Should I be concerned about that?

Comment: No, I don't think you need worry about that.

Comment: Here's the first three I can find in the site I've noticed this: **◉** [Nice sites for practicing dictation?](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1156) **◉** [Aren't kaomoji part of the Japanese language?](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/883) **◉** [Which way should you review vocabulary using flashcards? \[closed\]](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1137)

Answer (score 4):

All sites are regulated by their community; if a community decides that certain types of questions are okay on their Meta, then such questions are okay on their Meta.

The examples you cite *are* kind-of weird and would be off-topic on most Meta sites, but the Japanese Language site is still in Beta, the site community is still in the process of finding their feet. It may well be that in the *long run* such questions will no longer be acceptable there either.